# All of WiFi passwords seem to be lost on my iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi

Recently, I confirmed that my iPhone wasn’t connected to a WiFi network of a cafe I frequent. So I have to ask the staff for letting me know the password again.

At first I thought the cafe renewed the password recently. But later, I found out that the same happened to every cafe I have ever visited. It seems that all the WiFi network name and its password stored on my iPhone were lost. Also, the same happened to my iPad as well, which uses the same iCloud account.

This happened in the past as well, but I’m not sure what is the cause of it. I don’t like it to happen it again. So why does this happen and how can I prevent it? I’m sure I didn’t reset it manually, though it is possible that I have done something wrong that caused it to happen (e.g. logging out of the iCloud on one iOS device, reset my another iOS device that uses the same iCloud account, etc)...